# GWTUpload not showing file path

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

My project is in GWT Java using Eclipse Juno.

I am using GWTUpload however after selecting the picture the file path and file name are not displayed. How do I get the file path and name to display just before the "Browse" button after the picture is selected?

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

import gwtupload.client.IUploadStatus.Status;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader.UploadedInfo;
import gwtupload.client.MultiUploader;
import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage;
import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage.OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload;
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox.DefaultFormat;

public class EditYouthMemberView extends Composite {

private DBConnectionAsync rpc;
private TextBox textBoxFirstName;
private TextBox textBoxScoutNumber;
private ListBox listBoxSection;
private ListBox listBoxPack;
private TextBox textBoxSurname;
private DateBox dateBoxArchived;
private DateBox dateBoxPackIn;
private DateBox dateBoxPackOut;
private DateBox dateBoxDOB;
// A panel where the thumbnails of upload images will be shown
//final FlowPanel panelImages = new FlowPanel();
final HorizontalPanel panelImages = new HorizontalPanel();


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public EditYouthMemberView(final NavHandler navHandler) {       

    final java.util.Date todays_date = new java.util.Date();

    rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    verticalPanel.setStyleName("gwt-Banner");
    initWidget(verticalPanel);

    HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    horizontalPanel.setStyleName("gwt-Banner");
    verticalPanel.add(horizontalPanel);
    horizontalPanel.setWidth("246px");

    Label lblHome = new Label("Home");
    lblHome.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblHome);
    lblHome.setWidth("46px");

    Label lblEditAwards = new Label("Edit Awards");
    lblEditAwards.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblEditAwards);
    lblEditAwards.setWidth("85px");

    Label lblListAll = new Label("List all Cub Scouts");
    lblListAll.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblListAll);
    lblListAll.setWidth("130px");

    Label lblAccountUpdate = new Label("Account Update");
    lblAccountUpdate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblAccountUpdate);
    lblAccountUpdate.setWidth("104px");

    FlexTable flexTable_1 = new FlexTable();
    verticalPanel.add(flexTable_1);

    Label lblSurname = new Label("Surname");
    lblSurname.setWordWrap(false);
    lblSurname.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lblSurname.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 2, lblSurname);

    Label lblFirstName = new Label("First Name");
    lblFirstName.setWordWrap(false);
    lblFirstName.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lblFirstName.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 3, lblFirstName);

    textBoxSurname = new TextBox();
    flexTable_1.setWidget(1, 1, textBoxSurname);

    textBoxFirstName = new TextBox();
    flexTable_1.setWidget(1, 2, textBoxFirstName);      

    Label lblLookForPhotograph = new Label("Look for photograph:");
    lblLookForPhotograph.setWordWrap(false);
    lblLookForPhotograph.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lblLookForPhotograph.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable_1.setWidget(2, 1, lblLookForPhotograph);
    flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(2, 1, 3);

    // Attach the image viewer to the document
    flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 0, panelImages);
    panelImages.setSize("120", "120");
    flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 0, 4);
    panelImages.clear();

    // Create a new uploader panel and attach it to a document
    final MultiUploader defaultUploader = new MultiUploader();
    flexTable_1.setWidget(3, 1, defaultUploader);
    flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(3, 1, 3);

    // Add a finish handler which will load the image once the upload finishes
    defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);

    FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
    verticalPanel.add(flexTable);

    Label lblDOB = new Label("Date of Birth:");
    lblDOB.setWordWrap(false);
    lblDOB.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, lblDOB);
    lblDOB.setDirectionEstimator(false);
    lblDOB.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblDOB.setSize("110px", "16px");

    dateBoxDOB = new DateBox();
    dateBoxDOB.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, dateBoxDOB);
    dateBoxDOB.getDatePicker();

    Label lblSection = new Label("Section:");
    lblSection.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblSection.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 2, lblSection);

    listBoxSection = new ListBox();
    listBoxSection.addItem("Cubs");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 3, listBoxSection);
    listBoxSection.setVisibleItemCount(1);

    Label lblScoutNumber = new Label("Scout Number:");
    lblScoutNumber.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblScoutNumber.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 0, lblScoutNumber);
    lblScoutNumber.setDirectionEstimator(false);
    lblScoutNumber.setSize("110px", "16px");

    textBoxScoutNumber = new TextBox();
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 1, textBoxScoutNumber);

    Label lblPack = new Label("Pack:");
    lblPack.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblPack.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 2, lblPack);

    listBoxPack = new ListBox();
    listBoxPack.addItem("Explorer");
    listBoxPack.addItem("Pioneer");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 3, listBoxPack);
    listBoxPack.setVisibleItemCount(1);

    Label lblDateArchived = new Label("Date Archived:");
    lblDateArchived.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblDateArchived.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 0, lblDateArchived);
    lblDateArchived.setSize("110px", "16px");

    dateBoxArchived = new DateBox();
    dateBoxArchived.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 1, dateBoxArchived);
    dateBoxArchived.getDatePicker();

    Label lblIn_1 = new Label("In:");
    lblIn_1.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblIn_1.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 2, lblIn_1);

    dateBoxPackIn = new DateBox();
    dateBoxPackIn.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFullDateFormat()));
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 3, dateBoxPackIn);
    dateBoxPackIn.getDatePicker();

    Label lblNewLabel_3 = new Label("Out:");
    lblNewLabel_3.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 4, lblNewLabel_3);

    dateBoxPackOut = new DateBox();
    dateBoxPackOut.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    dateBoxPackOut.getDatePicker();

    flexTable.setWidget(2, 5, dateBoxPackOut);

    Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
    btnAdd.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Integer tracker = 0;
            if (textBoxSurname.getText().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 1; 
            }
            if (textBoxFirstName.getText().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 2; 
            }
            // if (panelImages.getFilename().length() == 0) {
            //  tracker = tracker + 4; 
            // }
            if (dateBoxDOB.toString().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 8; 
            }
            if (dateBoxPackIn.toString().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 16; 
            }

            if (tracker == 1) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname.");
            }
            if (tracker == 2) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name.");
            }
            if (tracker == 3) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname and First Name");
            }
            if (tracker == 4) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph.");
            }
            if (tracker == 5) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname and select a photograph.");
            }
            if (tracker == 6) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a FirstName and select a photograph.");
            }
            if (tracker == 7) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name and select a photograph");
            }
            if (tracker == 8) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 9) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname and DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 10) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name and DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 11) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, First Name and DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 12) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph and enter a BOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 13) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, select a photograph and enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 14) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a FirstName, select a photograph and enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 15) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name, select a photograph and enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 16) {
                Window.alert("Please enter date joined Pack");
            }

            if (tracker == 17) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname and date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 18) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name and date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 19) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 20) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph and enter date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 21) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, select a photograph and enter date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 22) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name, select a photograph and enter date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 23) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name, select a photograph and enter date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 24) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 25) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 26) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name, DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 27) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, First Name, DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 28) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph, enter a BOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 29) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, select a photograph, enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 30) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a FirstName, select a photograph, enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 31) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name, select a photograph, enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }

            //if (tracker == 0) {
            //  AsyncCallback<YthMmbrSectDtls> callback = new CreationHandler<YthMmbrSectDtls>(null);
            //  rpc.createYouthMember(null, textBoxSurname.getText(), textBoxFirstName.getText(), dateBoxDOB.getValue(), 
            //          fileUpload.getFilename(), dateBoxArchived.getValue(), null, listBoxSection.getItemText(listBoxSection.getSelectedIndex()),
            //          listBoxPack.getItemText(listBoxPack.getSelectedIndex()), dateBoxPackIn.getValue(), 
            //          dateBoxPackOut.getValue(), callback);
            //}

        }

    });
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 0, btnAdd);

    Button btnUpdate = new Button("Update");
    btnUpdate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    btnUpdate.setText("Update");
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 1, btnUpdate);

    Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 2, btnCancel);

    Button btnClearPage = new Button("Clear Page");
    btnClearPage.setText("Clear Page");
    btnClearPage.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            textBoxSurname.setText("");
            textBoxFirstName.setText("");
            dateBoxDOB.setValue(null);
            dateBoxPackIn.setValue(todays_date);
            dateBoxPackOut.setValue(null);
            textBoxScoutNumber.setText("");
            dateBoxArchived.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 3, btnClearPage);
    setStyleName("body");
}

// Load the image in the document and in the case of success attach it to the viewer
private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
    public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
        if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
            new PreloadedImage(uploader.fileUrl(), showImage);

            //The server sends useful information to the client by default
            UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();
            System.out.println("File name " + info.name);
            System.out.println("File content-type " + info.ctype);
            System.out.println("File size " + info.size);

            // You can send any customised message and parse it
            System.out.println("Server message " + info.message);
        }
    }
};

// Attach an image to the pictures viewer
private OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
    public void onLoad(PreloadedImage image) {
        image.setWidth("75px");
        panelImages.add(image);
    }
};

/**
 * Decodes the base64 string into byte array to display image
 * Calls Base64Decode.java
 * @param imageDataString - a {@link java.lang.String}
 * @return byte array
 */
public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return Base64Decode.decode(imageDataString);
    }

public IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler getOnFinishUploaderHandler() {
    return onFinishUploaderHandler;
}

public void setOnFinishUploaderHandler(IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler) {
    this.onFinishUploaderHandler = onFinishUploaderHandler;
}

}
```

This is what happens:
Start screen where I select a photograph
[image]

I select a photograph and it automatically starts to load. While it is loading the path can be seen
[image]

Once the photograph has completed automatically displaying the file path disappears.
[image]

Comment: Please describe required source code , not all. I am ok it with common.io.fileupload.

Answer (score 1):

A MultiUploader listens for change events on the underlying input element and automatically uploads the selected file to the server. Then it creates a new form so more files can be selected. So you'll never be able to see the location/name next to the Browse button.

It looks like you only want to select a single file (if I read your code correctly) you might consider using a different implementation of IUploader such as `gwtupload.client.SingleUploader`.

Comment: Thank you very much nwilde97. Ihave instigated the SingleUploader as you suggested and will start another thread on its use. However, it seems very strange that the GWTUploader has a space for the path but does not use it. After all the previous FileUpload that I used did display the path. Also, if I select the same file twice GWTUploader does display the path. Regards, Glyn

Comment: OK, I have done some experimenting. If I set defaultUploader.setAutoSubmit(false) then I get the path displayed; however I need to select a new "Send" button that appears to display the photograph. How can I have the best of both worlds - display the path and the photograph automatically? I notice that when this is set to true that the path is displayed for a very short time while the photograph is loading. Once the photograph is displayed the path is removed. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

Using MultiUploader, each uploaded file-name is shown in a row before the browser button.

You have to include the Upload.css file in your app, normally done via the module.gwt.xml.

The file-path, though, is not shown because it is not returned by the FileInput used in some browsers because of security restrictions. So to be coherent it displays only the name.

BTW: I have tested your code and I get the name of the file selected (obviously not the path).

[EDIT]

You are using native the `input file`, gwtupload resets the input file when the upload finishes, so this is the reason you dont see the filename. In your case you need a label to update the text once the file has been sent.

[EDIT-2]

This could work for you:

```
final Label fileName = new Label();
flexTable_1.setWidget(n, n , fileName);

defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(new OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
  public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
    if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
        fileName.setText(uploader.getFileName);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Manolo, as per above I have changed to SingleUploader and set defaultUploader.setAutoSubmit(true). Using IE10 the path is displayed to the left of the button until the picture is displayed. Once the picture is displayed the field to the left of the button is blank. So why is the file name (which would be good enough for me) displayed for you? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont follow you, maybe a screenshot about what you see and what you would like could be helpful.

Comment: Hi Manolo, I have added the screen shots and description above. Thanks, Glyn

Comment: Hi Manolo, I have found the source of the file name (info.name). However, for the life of me I can not work out where / how to set it for the output. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Manolo, This returns "C:\fakepath\picture.jpg". Also, this creates a new label rather than displaying the path in the original place (before the browse button). So it looks like what I want to do is not possible. I think it is best that I concentrate on the next step of writing the picture to the MySQL database. I greatly appreciate your patience in dealing with a novice programmer. Regards, Glyn.